# SQL SERVE 2008 - BACKUP

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Necesito AYUDA tengo un error hice un backup y lo cambie a la opcion DISK pero antes estaba por defecto TAPE. Como le puedo poner por defecto, por favor

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por defecto deberías de utilizar el código. Mediante código se puede automatizar cualquier proceso y ahorrar mucho tiempo.

Comment: @LuisCazares el problema es que eso estaba por defecto con la opcion TAPE, solo me piden que lo deje por defecto asi. Nose como regresarlo en esa opcion, si tu sabes por codigo...eso hara que lo deje por defecto en esa opcion? AYUDA :s

Answer (score 0):

Solo tienes que darle al botón "Add..." y allí en vez de un archivo le indicas el dispositivo con el que quieres realizar el backup.

El dispositivo de cinta, previamente debe haberse registrado, [ver documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/define-a-logical-backup-device-for-a-tape-drive-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: aun sigue en la opcion DISK, no cambia a la opcion TAPE

Comment: Mírate este [enlace de la documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/define-a-logical-backup-device-for-a-tape-drive-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)